# How to add a UISplitViewController to a window-based app

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, xib, xcode3.2, universal-binary

If I create a new project in Xcode 3 - a "Universal" window based project, I can't seem to instantiate the UISplitViewController outlet I am adding to the iPad's XIB.

Starting with a brand new "window-based" project, I select "Universal" from the drop down (iPhone, iPad, Universal). I then create an IBOutlet property in AppDelegate_iPad.h, synthesize the variable in the .m file and release it in the appropriate dealloc.

I open MainWindow_iPad.xib file and add a UISplitViewController object to it. I then connect the "splitViewController" outlet from AppDelegate_iPad to the UISplitViewController I just dragged onto the XIB.

Unfortunately, when I run this, splitViewController is never instantiated. Consequently, I can't add it to the window's view or set it as the window's root controller. I check this by putting a break point in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

to view the splitViewController ivar - but unfortunately, it is always 0x0. Is there some special step I am missing? I've compared my code to the split view controller template in Xcode and I can't see any differences.